# How to access data from mutation request response after redirect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am setting up the creation of a new user and email verification for my application.
So for sign up request I'm using query mutation and in the response from the server I'm getting the data of the created user: name, email, id.
I can access this data in my SignUp component using `data` from my `useSignUpMutation()` hook.
But then if the request is fine I'm doing redirect to a `Verification` component that shows standard "check your email please" text. I'm redirecting there with `<Navigate />` from
`react-router-dom`.
So now I want to access that same data from that `useSignUpMutation()` operation in another component, but I can't. The data is just undefined there.
I of course can create a slice for that data and just save with that slice, but I don't want to add extra complexity for such a small operation. I also can do Verification as a pop up module so I don't need to redirect from that page. But is there a way access that data from another page?

My signUp component:

```
export const SignUpPage = () => {
  const [signUp, { data }] = useSignUpMutation();

  console.log(data); // gives me data

  if (data) {
    return <Navigate to="/confirm-email" />;
  }

  return (
    <Page>
      <SignUp onSubmit={signUp} />
    </Page>
  );
};
```

My verification component ( I need to get the data here)

```
export const SendConfirmation = () => {
  const [resendVerification] = useResendVerificationMutation();
  const [signUp,  { data }] = useSignUpMutation();

  console.log(data); // data is undefined

  const handleResendVerification = () => {
    resendVerification({});
  };

  return (
    <Page>
      <Card className={s.modal}>
        <Button type="button" onClick={handleResendVerification}>
          Resend verification letter
        </Button>
      </Card>
    </Page>
  );
};
```

So I guess the things is that when I redirect to another page, RTK doesn't see that data from the last response as valid. So the question is how to access invalid cache in this case?

store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { baseApi } from "./base-api";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [baseApi.reducerPath]: baseApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(baseApi.middleware),
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

base api:

```
export const baseApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "baseApi",
  tagTypes: ["Decks", "Auth"],
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth, (it's a huge chunk of code from redux docs)
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

Service with injected endpoints:

```
import { baseApi } from "../base-api";

export const AuthService = baseApi.injectEndpoints({
  
  endpoints: (builder) => {
    return {
      authMe: ... ,
      login: ...,
      logout: ...,
      signUp: builder.mutation<SignUpResponseType, SignUpArgsType>({
        query: (body) => ({
          url: "v1/auth/sign-up",
          method: "POST",
          body,
        }),
        // invalidatesTags: ["Auth"],
      }),
      verifyEmail: ... ,
      resendVerification: ...,
  },
});
```

So I ended up passing the data through state object of `react-router-dom` `navigate` method and then accessing it with `useLocation` hook

Comment: My guess is that `useSignUpMutation()` internally calls `useContext(...)` to try to get the data. Maybe your `verification component` isn't wrapped inside a react context provider while your `signUp component` is?

Comment: No, it's fine. I can access other properties from the hook like isLoading, isError etc. just the data is undefined.

Comment: Do you just need to pass this `data` value to the `"/confirm-email"` route and access it in `SendConfirmation` component?

Comment: yes, that's the goal. But now I'm also wondering if it's possible to access invalid cache.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include your Redux code, the store and API slice code? See [mcve]. It might be that the mutation data isn't being held onto. You might need to pass it in route state when navigating.

Comment: yes the solution with the route state is my go to so far. Just wondering about other ways